# Por que não podemos destruir [usando unset em] uma variável estática?

Tags: php, variáveis

Eu estava fazendo uns testes com variáveis estáticas de uma classe e acabei me deparando com um `Fatal Error`.

Veja:

```
class Stack
{
    public static $overflow = 'english';

    public $user;
}

Stack::$overflow = 'portuguese';

unset(Stack::$overflow);
```

O `unset` gera o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Attempt to unset static property `Stack::$overflow`

Por que o PHP não permite destruir [usando unset em] uma variável estática de uma classe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `unset()` é para elementos de arrays, variáveis e atributos de objetos.

Não é possível excluir uma propriedade de uma classe declarada no escopo da mesma, independente do tipo de declaração ou tipo de dados.

Para propriedades estáticas é emitido como fatal error pois as variáveis estáticas são alocadas em espaços de empilhamentos de valores como links de referência.

Ok, sabemos o que são arrays e variáveis, no entanto, o que seria "atributos de objetos"?

Exemplo:

```
    $a = new stdClass();
    $a->foo = 'test';
    $var_dump($a);
    /*
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
      ["foo"]=>
      string(4) "test"
    }
    */

    unset($a->foo);
    var_dump($a);
    /*
    object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
    }
    */
```

Note que um objeto inteiro também pode ser excluído quando atribuído como uma instância. Mas isso não quer dizer que a classe será excluída.

```
$a = new stdClass();
unset($a);

class Bar{}
$a = new Bar();
unset($a);
```

Para propriedades não declaradas como estáticas, um fatal error não é emitido, pois a propriedade, quando pública, torna-se membro da nova instância do objeto e não da classe original em si:

```
class Foo {
public $bar = 'bar';
}

$obj = new Foo;
print_r($obj);
unset($obj->bar); // Aqui excluímos a propriedade
print_r($obj); // Vejamos se realmente foi exluída

$obj = new Foo;
print_r($obj); // Veja o que acontece se, logo em seguida criamos uma nova instância. A propriedade original permanece inalterada -pois trata-se de uma nova instância.
```

Answer (score 2):

Variáveis declaradas no corpo da classe são **propriedades**, imagine que você programe uma classe:

```
class Cachorro
{
    public $Altura;
    public $Idade;
}
```

Altura e idade são propriedades de todos objetos do tipo cachorro, então qualquer função que receber um objeto desse, vai supor que essas propriedades existem dentro do objeto.

Agora imagina comigo, um outro programador fez uma função pra imprimir as propriedades do cachorro:

```
function ImprimeCachorro ($CachorroTop)
{
    echo 'Idade:' . $CachorroTop->Idade . ' Altura:' . $CachorroTop->Altura;
}
```

Agora vamos supor que por algum motivo ele recebe um objeto onde o PHP permitiu que a propriedade Altura fosse removida, o cachorro agora vive em outra dimensão.

Obviamente iria dar pau no código na hora de executar, mas aí esse outro programador vai olhar pra sua classe Cachorro e falar: "WTF?! Você me disse que o cachorro tinha essas 2 propriedades mas quando recebo ele só tem 1 delas.".

Então, remover propriedades de objetos seria o mesmo que violar um contrato. O fato de ser estática ou não apenas influencia se a propriedade é exclusiva de cada objeto (comum) ou se é compartilhada entre todos eles (estática).

Linguagens como JavaScript permitem que você adicione e remova váriveis de "objetos" de acordo com seu critério, porém isso só é possivel porque JavaScript NÂO é orientado a objeto, cada "objeto" nele é na verdade uma array associativa onde você associa um nome a um valor.

Answer (score 1):

Da uma olhada na documentação, la fala:

Se for utilizado unset() com uma variável estática dentro de uma função, unset() destrói a variável somente no contexto do resto da função. Chamada seguintes irão restaurar o valor anterior da variável. todas as suas referências.

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    static $bar;
    $bar++;
    echo "Before unset: $bar, ";
    unset($bar);
    $bar = 23;
    echo "after unset: $bar\n";
}

foo();
foo();
foo();
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```
Before unset: 1, after unset: 23
Before unset: 2, after unset: 23
Before unset: 3, after unset: 23
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php

Comment: Mas e a questão da classe? Eu gostaria de entender por que quando usamos em uma propriedade de uma classe gera `Fatal Erro`!

Comment: uma nota importante, esse tipo de execução poderá entrar como deprecated ou completamente abolido futuramente. Atualmente emite "notice strict" por não possuir declaração explícita do tipo de visibilidade da classe e seus respectivos membros (propriedades e métodos)